# Set Image in VB

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox

Ok so I am trying to make a loading screen with six dots lighting up then resetting until it finished loading.  The first two dots change pictures but the third doesn't!  How do I fix this! My code:

```
If picbox1.image is image1 then
  picbox1.image = image 2
ElseIf picbox1.image is image 2
  picbox2.image = image 2
ElseIf picbox2.image is image 2
  picbox3.image = image 2
```

This is all inside a timer with an interval of 1000 (1 second)

Here are my project files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4qf8zlyrz1616s/The%20Eye%20OS.zip

Comment: Well it looks like you are changing the image form image 1 to image 2. But you keep changing to image 2 after.

Comment: Yes I need the current picture box with (image 1) to change to the image to show it is loading(image 2). Pictureboxs 1 and 2 change but 3 doesn't

Comment: So you want to change `picbox2` to `image2`, then change `picbox3` to `image2`?

Comment: Yes all the picture boxes will change to image 2 after a one second interval each and then once they are all image 2 they will reset to image 1 and then repeat

Comment: ... then you want to change the `ElseIf ...` lines to say `Is image 1` don't you?!

Comment: I don't understand? I want all six picture boxes to be image 2 before changing back to image 1. Also you can download my source and see my problem. Please also edit my code to explain to me my problem

Comment: And Picturebox3 doesn't change to image2 so that is where I am stuck. There are no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "Not" after the Elseifs

```
If picbox1.image is image1 then
 picbox1.image = image 2
ElseIf Not picbox2.image is image 2
 picbox2.image = image 2
ElseIf Not picbox3.image is image 2
 picbox3.image = image 2
'So on
End If
```

I checked your project and this is the complete solution for you below:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Dot1.Image Is UnDot Then
        Dot1.Image = LoDot
    ElseIf Not Dot2.Image Is LoDot Then
        Dot2.Image = LoDot
    ElseIf Not Dot3.Image Is LoDot Then
        Dot3.Image = LoDot
    ElseIf Not Dot4.Image Is LoDot Then
        Dot4.Image = LoDot
    ElseIf Not Dot5.Image Is LoDot Then
        Dot5.Image = LoDot
    ElseIf Not Dot6.Image Is LoDot Then
        Dot6.Image = LoDot
    Else
        Dot1.Image = UnDot
        Dot2.Image = UnDot
        Dot3.Image = UnDot
        Dot4.Image = UnDot
        Dot5.Image = UnDot
        Dot6.Image = UnDot
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just want to know why that would fix it. I will try it but I want to why it might fix it?

Comment: Thats because u r checking if it has image 2 then set its image as image 2, that won't work because it doesn't have image 2 in the first place

Comment: Oh...ok will try then will respond. Could be a bit, not at my computer.